# Strange syntax error in print function after loop list append

Tags: python

i want to get a list of numbers, but i got an error, when trying to run it

[image]

```
lista=[]
for i in range(1,10):
    lista.append(i)
print(lista)
```

```
File "<blender_console>", line 3
    print(lista)
        ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also tried it on a common python compiler and it works just fine, but in blender it isn't

[image]

Comment: related blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45233/why-do-i-get-this-unexpected-syntax-error-on-the-python-console?rq=1

Comment: Hi, Bicukow, this does seem to be a duplicate... if for some reason the other answer doesn't work for you, by all means edit to reopen.

Comment: because the `print(lista)` is inside the `for loop` scope denoted as `...`.